# add custom Class to alert dialog in bootbox bootstrap jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I am using [Bootbox jquery plugin](http://bootboxjs.com/) to show modals.

this is a simple usage of that to show alert dialogs :

```
bootbox.alert({
     title: 'Message Title',
     message: "this is message Body"
});
```

This plugin has a `className` option to add custom Classes to apply to the dialog wrapper created by `dialog()` method but we can not use it for `alert()` method.

a way to add custom classes to `alert()` is use `dialog()` to create those. but in this case we must create buttons like **OK** (or **Cancel** in`prompt()` method) manually every time that we want an simple Alert that is Is time consuming, like this:

```
bootbox.dialog({
  message: "I am a custom dialog",
  title: "Custom title",
  buttons: {
    success: {
      label: "Success!",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback: function() {
        Example.show("great success");
      }
    }
});
```

is there any way to add custom classes to alert boxes via `alert()` method?

Comment: mate i tried `className` in alert box initialization and it worked fine, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zpekney2/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good news! You can set `className` also with alert (check the snippet).

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  bootbox.alert({
     title: 'Message Title',
     message: "this is message Body",
     className: "my-popup"
  });
});
```

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  bootbox.alert({
     title: 'Message Title',
     message: "this is message Body",
     className: "my-popup"
  });
});
```

```css
.my-popup .modal-content {
  background: #FAEBD7;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```